# What antonym exists for the word мука?

Tags: одним-словом

There is a Russian word **мука́** (which means *flour* in English)

What antonym exists for this word?

Comment: Leaving Russian aside, what, conceptually, would be an antonym to "flour"? Wheat? Gravel? Soot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all nouns have antonyms.

Only nouns that express a quality, or an object/subject with a specific quality, can have antonyms, e.g. молодость - старость, скупердяй - транжира. The word "мука" refers to a specific object, not a quality, so it has no antonyms.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: Is it транжир or транжира? My dictionary has both...

Comment: @Blaszard there are both indeed.

Answer (score 4):

In case you meant the word that's spelled the same, but stressed on the first syllable, it means "suffering" and its antonym would be "удовольствие" (pleasure).

Comment: _which means flour in English_...